# Access layout of one class in another?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have a custom ListView in which there is a textview and an image. I have set onclicklistener for imageview in my customlistadapter class, so I need to make some changes in main layout when the image is clicked. See the below code for reference...

**MainActivity.java**

```
hmDataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long arg1) {

            DataFields dataField = (DataFields) hmDataList
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
            ImageView v = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);
            RelativeLayout mainRL = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldMainRL);
            }
```

}

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        holder = null;
        DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
            holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);
            final View clickView = convertView;
            holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    count++;
                    clickView.setBackgroundColor(color.list_row_bg);
                    //
                    //Some changes has to be made for the main activity's layout
                    //
                }
            });
        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hmFieldName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:text="@string/no_data"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#F2F2F2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hmFieldDeleteImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
```

**activity_main.xml** has some widgets which are hidden, so I need to unhide them when the Image in the custom ListView is clicked.

To put it simple, Is there any way to update the gui of main activity from other class?
Any kind of help or example or reference is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good way to do it:

In your **MainActivity.java** add :

```
public onClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                count++;
                view.setBackgroundColor(color.list_row_bg);
                //
                //Some changes has to be made for the main activity's layout
                //

               // Here you can delete add or do anything to your views
            }

  };
```

and when you create a new CustomListAdapter object:

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new .....;
adapter.setActivity(this);
```

and In your **CustomListAdapter.java** add :

```
 private MainActivity mActivity;


 public void setActivity(MainActivity activity){
          mActivity = activity;
 }
```

and In your getView method:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        holder = null;
        DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);

             ....  Same Code

        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);
        final View clickView = convertView;
// use this code
        holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(mActivity.mListener);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

}
```

Comment: I didnt get this part of yours...


and when you create a new CustomListAdapter object:

CustomListAdapter adapter = new .....;
adapter.setActivity(this);


what do you mean by this?

Comment: I tried this, its not working, in OnClickListener of MainActivity I tried unhiding a widget of main layout but it gave NullPointerException. I think this implementation of yours is same as my previous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

on the other activity before you defined whether the image/button is hidden first or no.

on you OnClick put `setContentView(yourmainActivity)` then defined your `ImageView` which is invisible . then do your method to make visible back. P.S put the code after startActivity. 
hope that helps you.